# Android : Big error while downloading images

Tags: android

I have tried three ways of downloading images. All suggest by members of Stackoverflow .
All the three methods fail to download all the images from the server. Few are downloaded and few are not.

I noticed a thing that each of the method fail to download image from particular position.
That is method 3 always fails to download the first three images. I changed the images but even then , the first three images are not downloaded.

Method 1:

```
 public Bitmap downloadFromUrl( String imageurl )
   {
       Bitmap bm=null;
       String imageUrl = imageurl;
       try {
               URL url = new URL(imageUrl); //you can write here any link

              URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();


             InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
              BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);


               ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
              int current = 0;
              while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                       baf.append((byte) current);
              }

             bm= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baf.toByteArray(), 0, baf.toByteArray().length);


     } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
     }
       return bm;

   }
```

Here the error i get for missed images is :SKIimagedecoder , the factory returned null.

Method: 2

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) 
   {
       Bitmap bitmap = null;
       InputStream in = null;
       BufferedOutputStream out = null;

       try {
           in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), 4*1024);

           final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream,  4 * 1024);

           int byte_;
           while ((byte_ = in.read()) != -1)
               out.write(byte_);
           out.flush();

           final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           //options.inSampleSize = 1;

           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e);
           Log.e("","Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
       } finally {
           try{
               in.close();
               out.close();
           }catch( IOException e )
           {
               System.out.println(e);
           }
       }

       return bitmap;
   }
```

The error i get here is same as above.

Method 3:

```
private Bitmap downloadFile(String fileUrl){
    URL bitmapUrl =null;  
    Bitmap bmImg = null;
    try {
        bitmapUrl= new URL(fileUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

    try {
            httpRequest = new HttpGet(bitmapUrl.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                .execute(httpRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
        InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
    }
    return bmImg;
}
```

The error i get here is : org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond.

please help. It is the only thing stopping me from completing the project.

Comment: Does it do this only on one server, or on all servers? Could it be a serverside problem? Have you tried a different location to download te files from, just for test?

Comment: No i hvaen't tried downloading from other servers.

Comment: please try that. Seeing as you are trying 3 different methods (haven't checked them, but I assume you have), my first suspicion would be the other side of things. (or something in between, like the connection)

Comment: Ya, all of them are working. I don't have another server.

Comment: Can you show us the list of the urls that you are trying to download (or at least the first 3-4)? (I assume you call it in a loop)

Comment: @rajivpradeep your bounty ends pretty soon, you should either start responding to some answers or awarding the points

Comment: I haven't got the answer that worked for me yet.

Comment: @rajivpradeep then you should comment on answers to describe what happens when you try it. No one can help you if you don't work with us

Comment: @CameronW , i have explained every thing in the question. and edits. and i have replied to the answers too

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.. Clearly explained about image download from the Server..[Image from Server](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)....

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are downloading the images to display rather than just save on the device. If this is the case, I recommend looking into using [Droid-Fu](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/introducing-droid-fu-for-android-betteractivity-betterservice-and-betterasynctask/), more specifically [WebImageView](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/23/droid-fu-part-2-webimageview-and-webgalleryadapter/). You can just pass the URL to the WebImageView and it will load the image as it can, which will avoid having an image fail to load because of the connection timing out, which I'm guessing is the problem you are having.

In XML:

```
<com.github.droidfu.widgets.WebImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    droidfu:autoLoad="true"
    droidfu:progressDrawable="..."
/>
```

In Code:

```
WebImageView  image = (WebImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageUrl(image_url);
image.loadImage();
```

Comment: This is not what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your creation of bitmaps takes time and therefore the connection times out. You could possibly get references to all the inputstreams and then download and create. This is a rough-cut answer, but if the reasoning is right, you can improve on it:

```
public Bitmap[] downloadFromUrl(String[] imageUrls)
{
    Bitmap[] bm = new Bitmap[imageUrls.length];
    BufferedInputStream[] bis = new BufferedInputStream[imageUrls.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrls[i]); // you can write here any link
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            bis[i] = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bis.length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis[i].read()) != -1)
            {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            bm[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baf.toByteArray(), 0, baf.toByteArray().length);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return bm;

}
```

Comment: Most probably yes this is the problem that i am facing.