# URLConnection getContentLength() is returning a negative value

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Here is my code:

```
url = paths[0];
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int length = connection.getContentLength(); // i get negetive length
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
byte[] imageData = new byte[length]; 
int buffersize = (int) Math.ceil(length / (double) 100);
int downloaded = 0;
int read;
while (downloaded < length) {
    if (length < buffersize) {
        read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length);
    } else if ((length - downloaded) <= buffersize) {
        read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length - downloaded);
    } else {
        read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, buffersize);
    }
    downloaded += read;
    publishProgress((downloaded * 100) / length);
}
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
        length);
if (bitmap != null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap created");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Bitmap not created");
}
is.close();
return bitmap;
```

I looked at this in Java documentation and the length is negative because of the following reason:

> "the number of bytes of the content, or a negative number if unknown. If the content >length is known but exceeds Long.MAX_VALUE, a negative number is returned."

What might be the reason for this? I am trying to download an image. I would like to point out that this is the fourth method that I am trying to download images. The other three are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360618/android-big-error-while-downloading-images).

**Edit:**

As requested, here is the full method I am using.

```
protected Bitmap getImage(String imgurl) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(imgurl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int length = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        byte[] imageData = new byte[length];
        int buffersize = (int) Math.ceil(length / (double) 100);
        int downloaded = 0;
        int read;
        while (downloaded < length) {
            if (length < buffersize) {
                read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length);
            } else if ((length - downloaded) <= buffersize) {
                read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, length
                        - downloaded);
            } else {
                read = is.read(imageData, downloaded, buffersize);
            }
            downloaded += read;
        //  publishProgress((downloaded * 100) / length);
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,length);
        if (bitmap != null) {
             System.out.println("Bitmap created");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bitmap not created");
        }
        is.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two possible common explanations for this:

1. The content length is not known.  Or more specifically, the server is not setting a "Content-Length" header in the response message.
2. The content length is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  If that happens, `getContentLength()` returns `-1`.  (The javadocs recommend that `getContentLengthLong()` is used instead of `getContentLength()` to avoid that problem.)

Either way, it is better to NOT preallocate a fixed sized byte array to hold the image.

- One alternative is to create a local `ByteArrayOutputStream` and copy bytes read from the socket to that.  Then call `toByteArray` to grab the full byte array.
- Another alternative is to save the data in a temporary file in the file system.

Apparently a common underlying cause of this is that some implementations will by default request "gzip" encoding for the response data.  That forces the server to set the content length to -1.  You can prevent that like this:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

... but that means that the response won't be compressed.  So that is
(IMO) a substandard solution.

---

Your existing client-side code is broken in another respect as well.  If you get an IOException or some other exception, the code block will "exit abnormally" without closing the URLConnection.  This will result in the leakage of a file descriptor.  Do this too many times and your application will fail due to exhaustion of file descriptors ... or local port numbers.

It is best practice to use a try / finally to ensure that URLConnections, Sockets, Streams and so on that tie down external resources are ALWAYS closed.

---

Preallocating a buffer based on the (purported) content length sets you up for a denial of service attack.  Imagine what if the bad guys send you a lot of request with dangerously large "Content-Length" headers and then slow-send the data.  OOMEs or worse.

Comment: Any change that u recommended to  me in the application or on the server side. Any code that i need to add in here

Comment: I am indeed catching the exception, I haven't just posted that code above, all the above code resides inside try catch statements

Comment: It is not just a matter of catching the exception.  You have to close the connection in a finally block as well.

Comment: Hi i have added the complete code of the method that i am using in the edit.

Comment: Yes.  I see.  As I expected (and as I explained above), if an exception is thrown between opening the connection and closing the InputStream, your code is liable to leak a socket file descriptor.

Comment: When the server uses chunked transfer encoding (common for large payloads that get streamed) the content length is unknown and cannot be depended on.
It's very bad form to attempt to pre-allocate a buffer for the entire response anyway, can you say `denial of service`?
See the answer below regarding transfer encoding...

Answer (score 35):

By default, this implementation of HttpURLConnection requests that servers use gzip compression.
Since getContentLength() returns the number of bytes transmitted, you cannot use that method to predict how many bytes can be read from getInputStream().
 
Instead, read that stream until it is exhausted: when read() returns -1.
 
Gzip compression can be disabled by setting the acceptable encodings in the request header:

```
 urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

So try this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity"); // <--- Add this line
int length = connection.getContentLength(); // i get negetive length
```

Source (Performance paragraph): http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect Answer :)

Comment: Wow! this worked. I was about to throw my laptop :P thanks a bundle

Answer (score 3):

It seems the server doesn't offer **Content-Length** in its response headers, did you get the **Transfer-Encoding=chunked** header from the response headers?

My situation is : I perform a **HttpURLConnection** and consider the server would response to me the "Content-Length" with positive value, but it didn't, then I turn to
the **AndroidHttpClient** which android HttpClient implementation, perform the same request again and got the right **Content-Length**.

I used Wireshark to analysis the two requests, found a little difference about request headers.

the header list that use AndroidHttpClient :

```
---------------------------------- request headers
Range : bytpe=0-
Host : download.game.yy.com
Connection : Keep-Alive
User-Agent : com.duowan.mobile.netroid

---------------------------------- response headers
Server : nginx
Content-Type : text/plain; charset=utf-8
ETag : "535e2578-84e350"
Cache-Control : max-age=86400
Accept-Ranges : bytes
Content-Range : bytes 0-8708943/8708944
Content-Length : 8708944
```

the request header list that use HttpURLConnection :

```
---------------------------------- request headers
Range : bytpe=0-
Host : download.game.yy.com
Connection : Keep-Alive
User-Agent : com.duowan.mobile.netroid
Accept-Encoding : gzip    // difference here

---------------------------------- response headers
Server : nginx
Content-Type : text/plain; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control : max-age=86400
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
X-Android-Received-Millis : 1398861612782
X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1398861608538
```

The only difference with request header is **Accept-Encoding** which isn't added by myself, it was Android default setting for [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), after that, I set it to **identity** then perform request again, below is the full header stacks :

```
---------------------------------- request headers
Range : bytpe=0-
Host : download.game.yy.com
Connection : Keep-Alive
User-Agent : com.duowan.mobile.netroid
Accept-Encoding : identity

---------------------------------- response headers
Server : nginx
Content-Type : text/plain; charset=utf-8
ETag : "535e2578-84e350"
Cache-Control : max-age=86400
Accept-Ranges : bytes
Content-Range : bytes 0-8708943/8708944
Content-Length : 8708944
X-Android-Received-Millis : 1398862186902
X-Android-Sent-Millis : 1398862186619
```

as you can see, after I set the Accept-Encoding to "identity" replace system default value "gzip", the server provided "Content-Length" positive, that's why AndroidHttpClient could take the right value of Content-Length and HttpURLConnection not.

the gzip compression encoding may cause chunked response that consider by server-side, and if server think you can receive chunked encoding response, it may not offer the **Content-Length** header, try to disable gzip acceptable behavior then see what difference with that.

Comment: Be advised: turning off transfer encoding can cause performance issue on server, because most likely it can no longer "stream" whatever you requested, and has to "compute" the entire response before sending it.
Best plan is to not depend on that header, and just stream in.  This is independent of compression etc.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength%28%29

It says,

> **Returns:**
>
> the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, or -1 if the content length is not known.

It simply means header does not contains the `content-length` field. If you are having control over server code. You should set the content-lenth somehow. Something like [ServletResponse#setContentLength](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setContentLength%28int%29)

Comment: the content length of the resource that this connection's URL references, or -1 if the content length is not known.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem in my Wallpaper app. The problem is because your server doesn't provide **Content-Length** in its http header. Here is a snapshot about a normal http header with **Content-length**.

[image]

I am using a share host so I can not change the server configuration. In my app, I am set progress dialog max value with an approximated value (which is bigger than my real file size) like this:

```
int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
if(filesize < 0) {
    progressDialog.setMax(1000000);
} else {
    progressDialog.setMax(filesize);
}
```

You can also check my full example source code here:

[Android Progress Dialog Example](http://jmsliu.com/1929/android-progress-dialog-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am late here but this might help someone. I was facing same issue i was always getting **-1** value, when ever i was trying get the content length.

previously i was using below method to get content length.

```
long totalByte=connection.getContentLength();
```

I used below method which solved my problem .

```
long totalByte=Long.parseLong(connection.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
```