# Getting buffer capacity error while trying to download image located by a URL

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download images into a byte array but it gives me an error message,

What should I do?

```
05-29 12:28:13.324: D/ImageManager(6527): Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Buffer capacity may not be negative

byte []bg1=getLogoImage("http://onlinemarketingdubai.com/hotelmenu/images/874049310_gm.png");


private byte[] getLogoImage(String url){
    try {
        Log.d("Url",url);
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int length = conn.getContentLength();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(length);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        return baf.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
return null;
}
```

Comment: what is the line where this error appears? Have you checked if the input stream is good?

Comment: I have mention the  url it shows the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `ByteArrayBuffer` class:

```
public final class ByteArrayBuffer  {

  private byte[] buffer;
  private int len;

  public ByteArrayBuffer(int capacity) {
      super();
      if (capacity < 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer capacity may not be negative");
      }
```

You are initializing it passing it the `length` value as the buffer's `capacity` you aquired from:

```
int length = conn.getContentLength();
```

So the problem comes from the **connection length**, which I believe it's -1 since  the content length is not known. The server may  not be setting a "Content-Length" header in the response message.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428639/url-connection-returning-negative-value) for solving this.

Comment: Yup its giving me -1 length, but i am confused how to overcome this at android point, since i cannot change the image at server side, so what should i do to get the conn.getContentLenght() in positive

Comment: the issue you should find now is how to get a content-length from the response message. I think the reason of your issue, is, in fact, the non existance of a content length coming from the message.