# Java spring rest controller exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I write simple server-side file uploader code using java spring boot. Uploader works correctly, however firefox console displays very strange messages like this (after each sending chunk of file):

```
no element found
```

and some strange exception, listed only in browser and does not affect the execution of the uploader:

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at utils.Uploader.writeChunk(Uploader.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:947)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:946)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:994)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

This is piese of server code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/uploader")
public class Uploader 
{
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

   @RequestMapping("")
   public void writeChunk() throws IOException
    {
        int chunkLength = request.getContentLength();
        byte[] buf =  new byte[chunkLength];// exception throws in this line

            //here some other code
    }
}
```

This Exception means that the allocate size of buffer is negative, however debug shows correct value of the allocation size ( 1048576 bytes) - `chunkLength` and other behaviour looks correct.
What this mean?

Comment: What value is that? Log it and show it to us.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428639/url-connection-returning-negative-value

Comment: What if you change writeChunk(HttpServletRequest request) and remove global request var?

Comment: @mserioli, nothing changes - I tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at javadoc of **HttpServletRequest.getContentLength()**.

*Returns the length, in bytes, of the request body and made available by the input stream, or **-1 if the length is not known** or is greater than integer's max value.*