# I get java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1 on my blog

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, connection

I'm trying to create an application that Parse code from my website and display it on a listActivity. I've tried to use a couple of websites.. they all work fine. But then there is my website that shows this java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1 exception!

```
package com.example.hamad.jsonparsingverybasic;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "log";
    TextView network;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        network = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.networkStatus);

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            GetBlogPosts getBlogPosts = new GetBlogPosts();
            getBlogPosts.execute();
            network.setText("Network: Available!");
        } else {
            network.setText("Network: Not available!");
        }
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean netWorkAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            netWorkAvailable = true;
        }
        return netWorkAvailable;
    }

    private class GetBlogPosts extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
        int responseCode = 0;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {
                URL blogURL = new URL("http://trapedzone.com/api/info/");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogURL.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    try {
                        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                        int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
                        char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
                        reader.read(charArray);
                        String responseData = new String(charArray);
                        Log.v(TAG, responseData);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Bad response code: " + responseCode);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e);
            }
            return "Code: " + responseCode;
        }
    }
}
```

On executing, it throws java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1 exception on my site http://trapedzone.com but works perfectly when I use it on my other website http://trapedhost.com
Please help. Is there a problem with my website or that's something I can fix inside the java codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428639/android-url-connection-getcontentlength-returning-negative-value

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the stack trace.

However, there is only one line in your posted code that could generate that error:
    char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];

So, I would hazard a guess that connection.getCOntentLength() is returning -1.