# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411

Tags: java, server, httpurlconnection, ioexception

I am trying to post to a server the following URL:

http://localhost:3000/webserver/query?q=AddData(123,2015)

Using the code below, the server is returning error 411.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

try {
    //Create connection
    URL url = new URL(targetURL);

    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode("administrator:")); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    //Get Response  
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line;

    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }

    rd.close();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
  finally {
    if(connection != null) connection.disconnect(); 
  }
```

I know that error 411 is an invalid Content-Length method. I have tried giving the Content-Length the length of the URL but the error persisted.

Can you please help with this issue?

Comment: where are you setting the request body?

Comment: Doesn't look like you're actually making the request.

Comment: I just have the code above. Getting data from the server didn't give me any error. I just changed the requestMethod to GET and passed a get URL.

Comment: Why are you setting connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 0);? can you check connection.getContentLength();

Comment: Get the content length from connection and read those many bytes from InputStream

Comment: When I wrote this line 'connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(connection.getContentLength()));' I received the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428639/android-url-connection-getcontentlength-returning-negative-value

Comment: When I tried to see what the connection.getContentLength returned, it returned 0

Comment: Fixed, I had to send an empty string in the request body

Comment: @DavidFarrugia May you please add the code which you used to send an empty string in the request body?