# Google drive is sending length of file to -1 progressdialog android

Tags: android

Well i am showing the progressdialog with max 100 integer but it do not proceed due to the length of the file is always -1

```
 int lengthOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
....
publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
```

now the progressdialog always 0 as googledrive sending it -1
how can i fix it,i am making check update in my application,i use google drive because the link is same,i used dropbox before but it frequently get 404 error due to number of request for updates and then it blocks and send response from server data blocked
but google drive does not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428639/android-url-connection-getcontentlength-returning-negative-value This question is similar to the one asked here.

Comment: his answer wont helping using byteoutputstream ,cant make changes in google drive server