# length shows minus in progress bar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am downloading a video from a URL, when I am trying to get the progress it shows minus value, at below I have added my code,

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len1 = 0;
long total = 0;
while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    if (cancelDialogStatus) {
        break;
    }
    Log.e("System out", "doInBackground: progress:::" + len1);
    total += len1;
    // publishing the progress....
    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
    int prg = (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
    Log.d("System out", "doInBackground: progress:::" + prg);
    if (prg > 100) {
        publishProgress(""
                + 100);
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
        break;
    } else {
        publishProgress(""
                + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you getting _lenghtOfFile_?

Comment: HttpURLConnection con = null;
   try {
    downloadTimeStr = "";
    URL url = new URL("url") url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setConnectTimeout(Constants.STANDARD_TIMEOUT);
    // con.setDoOutput(true);
    try {
     con.connect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
     //ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    long lenghtOfFile = con.getContentLength();

Comment: Have you gone through [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428670/4492504)
It is basically due to the header parameter not being set by the server. Like when you download from gdrive it doesn't show total file size while download is in progress.

Comment: okay, Thank you so much... you solved my problem

Comment: your file length is -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically due to the `Content-Length` header parameter not being set by the server. Like when you download from Gdrive it doesn't show total file size while the download is in progress.

The simple answer is that the content length is not known. Or more specifically, the server is not setting a **Content-Length** header in the response message.

The detailed solution is [described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5428670/4492504)